# How to instantiate IModule-inheriting class from an AppDomain?

Tags: c#, dll, module, loading, appdomain

I'm a bit confused here and haven't gotten much help from google. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public Boolean LoadModule(String moduleHandle)//name of module MUST match its .dll name. Name of AppDomain is the same as the Handle.
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain moduleDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(moduleHandle);
            String pathToDll = @"C:\IModules.dll"; //Full path to dll you want to load
            Type moduleType = typeof(IModule);
            IModule loadedModule = (IModule)moduleDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, moduleType.FullName);

            ModuleList.Add(loadedModule, moduleDomain);
            Broadcast("Module loaded: " + moduleHandle, ModuleManagerHandle);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //console writeline the error? probably cant
            OutputBox.AppendText(e.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I thought I finally had this figured out but when I try to instantiate the IModule (ConsoleModule, in this case), I get the following error:
System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'IModules.IModule' not found.

I take this to mean that I need to have a constructor, as if this were a class object instantiating itself on this function call, but I cannot make an interface have a constructor.
I have seen other threads suggesting ways to solve this problem, but they use assembly instead of appdomain, which will mess up the ability to unload modules. I'm concerned that without the ability to unload modules the application will suffer memory bloating over time.

The end goal is to be able to write a module, leave the program running and load/unload the modules during runtime without any changes to the core program, and add functionality on the go.
Anyone know of a workaround or maybe a better way to deal with dynamic module loading and unloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed with .NET 5.0 AssemblyLoadContext:

```
var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            AssemblyLoadContext moduleAssemblyLoadContext = new AssemblyLoadContext(moduleHandle, true);
            Assembly moduleAssembly = moduleAssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath($"{basePath}\\{moduleHandle}.dll");

            Type[] types = moduleAssembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                // Does this class support the transport interface?
                Type typeModule = type.GetInterface("IModule");
                if (typeModule == null)
                {
                    // Not supported.
                    continue;
                }

                // This class supports the interface. Instantiate it.
                IModule loadedModule = moduleAssembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName) as IModule;
                if (loadedModule != null)
                {
                    loadedModule.LoadedModule(this);
                    ModuleList.Add(loadedModule, moduleAssemblyLoadContext);
                    Broadcast("Module loaded: " + moduleHandle, ModuleManagerHandle);
                    OutputTextBox.AppendText(moduleHandle + " was loaded." + Environment.NewLine);
                    // Successfully created the interface. We are done.
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
```

Can't find the source anymore but found it looking for a related problem (you can find it on MSDN anyways). This successfully loads and unloads assemblies into their context. User must set the isCollectible value to TRUE to enable full unloading.

Only issue I had is that .NET 5.0 is not compatible -with itself- yet and libraries loaded as .NET 5.0 into .NET 5.0 programs will give a BadImageFormatException when trying to load the assembly. To fix, set the LIBRARY to the next most recent target framework (in my case, .NET Core 3.1) and move the newly compiled dll to wherever it goes and the application should run using the new dll.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that there is no default (empty) constructor found for the type `IModule`. Since IModule is an interface, the message seems to make some sense.
Resulotion: Instantiate a `class` that implements `IModule`. An interface can never be intantiated on its own.
To instantiate the class, just one line neds to be changed:

```
Type moduleType = typeof(ClassThatImplementIModule);
```

You can still cast the instance to `IModule`

Comment: lidqy Thanks for the response.
I'm not actually trying to instantiate or cast into IModule, I just need the program to know the object does inherit the interface.
I'm not aware of any way to get the type of the class that inherits IModule (to call its constrctor) without using assembly.load, which would defeat the purpose of using AppDomain.
I actually don't WANT to know the type either if it can be avoided, I just need a way to instantiate this object, whatever it is, and know that it inherited IModule.

Comment: Of course you can't know which class of an assembly implements a certain interface, if you don't load that assembly. But since you already use a 2nd AppDomain which you can completly unload, I don't get the point why you fear to get into "memory bloat".
But anyhow I didn't really understand the whole purpose.
Do you want to work with that indsatnce (dynamicaly loaded) or do you just want to analyze types?

Comment: I you just want to just analyze assemblies `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` provides a light-wight way of loading assemblies. But you can't execute them in that context.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload?view=net-5.0

Comment: lidqy The goal is to get an instance of the class (the one inheriting IModule) and be able to call its interface methods. If you continue running the application and load tons of modules, even if you null their references the assemblies remain loaded in memory (memory bloat). That's what appdomain was intended for (ability to unload the entire appdomain), but I don't see a way to actually use it this way and it doesn't seem like anyone else has found that way either. I've made a copy of this solution for .NET 5 to look into AssemblyLoadContext and see whether that will work better.

Comment: But if you Unload the AppDomain, all its loaded assemblies unload as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/load-unload#load-and-unload-assemblies
So you actually should be able to handle the memory bloat.
In .NET5 just have 1 AppDomain.

Comment: lidqy yes, that's why I'm using appdomain. What I can't figure out here is "How to instantiate IModule-inheriting class from an AppDomain?" and return its reference (of type IModule, presumably). Nothing I've found anywhere shows how to actually do this. When I use the above code I get the indicated error and I haven't found another way.

Comment: So you want to work with the instance of `IModule` in the main AppDomain?
And you know that the other assembly ("C:\IModules.dll") contains an implementaion of IModule but you dont know the class name? Than you need to enumerate the types in "C:\IModules.dll" and check which implements IModule (e.g. using `IsAssignableFrom`). Than you have to create an instance of the class (assuming its ctor is paramless) than you need to unwrap it into your domain. But probaly you'll load the assembly also into the first appdomain that way i am not sure...

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. The ONLY reason to use appdomain is to isolate assembly so it can be unloaded later. Since you cannot do this without also loading the assembly separately to iterate through the types to instantiate an object that implements your interface, I'm not sure what even is the point of appdomain at all since you will still be forced to load the object in the main appdomain.

Comment: lidqy, I have corrected this problem with AssemblyLoadContext in .NET 5.0 Core, see the added solution. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Plaje  Glad you found a good solution. And thanks for introducing AssemblyLoadContext, seems pretty handy for sandbox-like assembly-loading stuff. Especially with that Unloading option...